# FTP giving 550 error when using ftp.cwd() twice

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

When I run this part:

```
directory = ftp.pwd()
file_name = 'config.single'
ftp.cwd('plugins/GAListener')
print('dir:', directory)
ftp.cwd('plugins/CrateReloaded/crates')
```

It says:

> ftplib.error_perm: 550 No such file or directory.

When I change the directory several times inside an if statement, it works fine.

Are you unable to change the working directory like that? Do I need to reset to the main server directory prior to changing to another? If so, how would I do that?

Whichever directory comes first in the code is the one it goes to, then gives an error upon trying to change to the second. With the second `ftp.cwd()` commented out, the first one runs without problem, no matter which directory it points to, so they're definitely both there.

Additionally, when I print `directory`, it just prints `/` and not `plugins/GAListener`.

Edit: When doing this inside an if statement, all the directories go where they're supposed to and I'm given no errors without a leading slash.

```
if day_of_week == 0 and file_name not in ftp.nlst():
    ftp.rename('config.yml', 'config.single')
    ftp.rename('config.double', 'config.yml')
    print('plugins/GAListener/config.yml is now plugins/GAListener/config.single.')
    print('plugins/GAListener/config.double is now plugins/GAListener/config.yml.')
    ftp.cwd('plugins/MOTDCountdown')
    ftp.rename('config.yml', 'config.sunday')
    ftp.rename('config.monday', 'config.yml')
    print('plugins/MOTDCountdown/config.yml is now plugins/MOTDCountdown/config.sunday.')
    print('plugins/MOTDCountdown/config.monday is now plugins/MOTDCountdown/config.yml.')
    ftp.cwd('plugins/Essentials')
    ftp.rename('motd.txt', 'motd.sunday')
    ftp.rename('motd.monday', 'motd.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `cwd` you end up in folder:

```
/plugins/GAListener
```

Changing to a relative path `plugins/CrateReloaded/crates` (without a leading slash) will resolve it against the current working directory. So it will attempt to open folder:

```
/plugins/GAListener/plugins/CrateReloaded/crates
```

Which most probably does not exist.

I assume you want to go to

```
/plugins/CrateReloaded/crates
```

For that you have to use an absolute path (with a leading slash):

```
ftp.cwd('/plugins/CrateReloaded/crates')
```

Comment: I see. So why does it work within an if statement? If I use `ftp.cwd(plugins/xxxx)` without a leading slash a couple times in a row, it works just fine.

Comment: I cannot answer that without a code example. Your description is too ambiguous.

Comment: Those are different folders + Can you enable logging for both your examples and post the log? `FTP.set_debuglevel`

Comment: I think I may have made a mistake in thinking I'd tried that if statement without a leading slash. Thank you for the help